# How BsonDocument casts to Command without a syntax error?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Obviosuly there is something I cannot see here as I expected that this line should cause a syntax error but it builds!

```
Command<BsonDocument> command = new BsonDocument(); // How this cast works, given the below class declarations???!!!

public class BsonDocument : BsonValue, IComparable<BsonDocument>, IConvertibleToBsonDocument, IEnumerable<BsonElement>, IEnumerable, IEquatable<BsonDocument>

public abstract class Command<TResult>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just before I post my question, I reccognised that there is an implicit operator in the Command class

```
public static implicit operator Command<TResult>(BsonDocument document);
```

I didn't know that is possible in C#, and I think it is a bad idea but it seems that MongoDB team did it for backward compatibility.